# Instantiating Wrapper objects in a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

**Update 1:** Added some sample pseudo-code to hopefully better try and explain
what I am aiming for.

I have a bunch of entities (`Entity1`, `Entity2`, `Entity3`) and their
associated Wrapper classes (`Entity1Wrapper`, `Entity2Wrapper`,
`Entity3Wrapper`), where the wrapper classes all implement `IWrapped<T>`:

```
public interface IWrapped<T>
{
    T GetWrapped();
}
```

Now in a generic method I run a query and get a `List` of entity objects.  I
want to wrap them in the suitable wrapper class before returning a list.
Basically I want my method to be declared as:

```
public IList<IWrapped<T>> GetAll<T>()
{
    IList<IWrapped<T>> retList = new List<IWrapped<T>>();

    //Get IList<T> entityList by querying

    foreach (T elem in entityList)
    {
        if (typeof(elem) == typeof(Entity1))
        {
            //Of course this code doesn't actually work, but the equivalent
            //of this is what I am trying to achieve
            retList.Add(new Entity1Wrapper(elem))
        }
        else if (typeof(elem) == typeof(Entity2))
            //instantiate Entity2Wrapper and store reference to elem in it
        else if (typeof(elem) == typeof(Entity3))
            //instantiate Entity3Wrapper and store reference to elem in it
    }
    return retList;
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this do-able?
2. Am I headed down the right path?
3. How do I actually do this

Would it help if all the entity classes implemented an empty interface (just to
give them a common base type; currently all are derived from `object`)?

Comment: If `T` is `Entity1`, I hardly see how you can sotre a reference to a `Entity2Wrapper` in a `IList<IWrapped<Entity1>`

Comment: @Guillaume If `T` is `Entity1`, I want to store it in `Entity1Wrapper`: `entityList.Add(new Entiy1Wrapper(elem))` . Of course, this pseudo-code doesn't actually work, but it is what I want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one method per type and common code in a private method :

```
public IList<IWrapped<Entity1>> GetAllEntity1()
{
    return GetAll<Entity1>.Select(e => new Entity1Wrapper(e)).ToList();
}

public IList<IWrapped<Entity2>> GetAllEntity2()
{
    return GetAll<Entity1>.Select(e => new Entity2Wrapper(e)).ToList();
}

//...

private IList<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    //Get IList<T> entityList by querying
    return entityList;
}
```

Or you can use an IoC to register implementations and inject them when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `GetWrapper<T>` static function to return the appropriate wrapper create function for type T.  The following function will return the correct wrapper for Entity1, Entity2, and Entity3 and an error for any other types that haven't been configured yet.

```
public static class GetWrapper<T>
{
    static GetWrapper()
    {
        GetWrapper<Entity1>.CreateWrapper = v => new Entity1Wrapper(v);
        GetWrapper<Entity2>.CreateWrapper = v => new Entity2Wrapper(v);
        GetWrapper<Entity3>.CreateWrapper = v => new Entity3Wrapper(v);
    }
    public static Func<T, IWrapped<T>> CreateWrapper { get; set; }
}

public IList<IWrapped<T>> GetAll<T>()
{
    IList<IWrapped<T>> retList = new List<IWrapped<T>>();

    //Get IList<T> entityList by querying
    IList<T> entityList = new List<T> { default(T) };

    var createWrapper = GetWrapper<T>.CreateWrapper;
    if (createWrapper == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Wrapper not found for type " + typeof(T).Name);
    }

    foreach (T elem in entityList)
    {
        retList.Add(createWrapper(elem));
    }
    return retList;
}
```